# DISM error: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: cmd.exe, prompt

I am a new member and this error is troubling me. When I try and download .NET framework 4.6.2 it says my component store is corrupt. I did some research and came up with the solution in command prompt (administrator) `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`. I ran this command and now it tells me that error: 3 "The system cannot find the path specified"

I have been trying to figure it out and fix it but can't get anywhere, any suggestions?

Comment: According to the tool. DISM is for the following.  Are you trying to fix an image or your running OS?
DISM enumerates, installs, uninstalls, configures, and updates features and packages in Windows images. The commands that are available depend on the image being serviced and whether the image is offline or running.

Comment: @uSlackr DISM works with deployed Windows installations too, including one that is currently running.

Comment: Im running windows 8.1, and ultimately want to 'un-corrupt' the component store.

Comment: To download .NET framework 4.6.2 the store needs to be fixed and I am stuck on what to do

Comment: If you just run `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` what happens?  If that fails to work, it means your missing the source file, required for it to work.  So download a Windows 8.1 ISO and run `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess` instead.

Comment: @Ramhound it says the component store is repairable

Comment: If you now run `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth` what happens?  If that runs sucessfully.  You should provide us `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` and `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log` we can then verify, if performing the repair, will solve anything.

Comment: operation was successfull

Comment: file:///C:/Windows/Logs/CBS/CBS.log            file:///C:/Users/JoJomoJo/Desktop/dism.log

Comment: You need to supply the log files to that sucessful operation.  Please edit your question, supply the command you used and the output to that command.  Edit your question to include **working** links to the files instead of links to inaccessible local files.  You don't have to indicate what you added, just add the information, the revision keeps track of all that.

Comment: @Ramhound im having to do a couple of errands i will try to complete all the taks when i get back

Comment: @Ramhound when supplying  the command Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth it outputs 'no component store corruption detected' - 'the operation completed successfully

Comment: @joegarner2106 - So because that last command, indicates your component store is not corrupt, running the command you want to run will not resolve your problem.  Of course if you still wanted to run it, `DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` would be the command.  You were getting an error because you were adding the `.exe` at the end.

Comment: @Ramhound so the component store is fully repaired?

Comment: @joegarner2106 - You can run the command to restore the health, but you checked the health (which will be done before the restore is attempted anyways) and the store isn't corrupt.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried downloading NET.framework since the component store seemingly had 'no corruption detected' but it still cancels the installation because the component store is still corrupt /:

Comment: You never published the log files.

Comment: @Ramhound how do I do so?

Comment: @joegarner2106 - I have no perference how you share the files.  We can't access your local drive, which is the only links, you provided to the files themselfs.

Comment: @Ramhound what would be the best way to share my local files?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem:

> E:\sources> DISM /APPLY-IMAGE /IMAGEFILE:E:\sources\INSTALL.WIM /INDEX:6 /APPLYDIR:K:
>
> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
> Version: 10.0.22621.1
>
> Error: 3
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

and I could not understand the problem because both e:\sources\INSTALL.WIM and f:\ exit.

So I followed the advice given by [majorgeeks.com](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/fix_dism_errors_231187508711217261393_or_0x800f081f.html):

> dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

With that I saw what the real problem is: my %TEMP% and %TMP% drive is set to a hard drive that I just pulled out of the system.  Strangely enough, when I try to recreate the problem by setting the environment variables TEMP and TMP to an non existing drive letter, I can still get error 3 but somehow `dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` no longer show any error.